# Are all cells of the human body completely replaced every seven to ten years?

Tags: biology, physiology

It have heard several times that, every seven to ten years, all the cells that our body are made of have all been replaced. Example in [this NY Times Article](http://www.nytimes.com/2005/08/02/science/02cell.html?pagewanted=all)

> This heartening truth, which arises from the fact that most of the body's tissues are under constant renewal, has been underlined by a novel method of estimating the age of human cells. Its inventor, Jonas Frisen, believes the average age of all the cells in an adult's body may turn out to be as young as 7 to 10 years.

Is this claim accurate?

Comment: Yeah, but even that would be akin to saying all people on the earth will be dead in 100 years.  It's only a statistical inference.  Of course few people live longer than 100 years, but it's not in any way an absolute statement.

Comment: I recall hearing that all *atoms* in the body are replaced every X period. Cells certainly arent' all ever replaced.

Comment: @BenBrocka that may have come from Carl Sagan IIRC

Answer (score 28):

**Different types of cells have different lifespans**, e.g.:

> - [we shed our **skin cells about every 35 days**](http://askabiologist.asu.edu/content/cells-divide)
> - [red **blood cells live about 120 days**, **platelets 6 days** and **white cells less than a day**](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/bloodandblooddisorders.html)
> - [most of the adult **skeleton is replaced about every 10 years**](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK45504/)
> - [the average age of a **fat cell** seems to be about **10 years**](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v453/n7192/full/453169a.html)
> - [a **25-year-old heart replaces about 1% of all its cardiomyocytes** (*heart muscle cells* ) **over the course of a
>     year**, while a 75-year-old heart replaces about half a percent](http://www.nih.gov/researchmatters/april2009/04132009heartcells.htm)
> - [our **neocortical neurons**, the cell type that mediates much of our cognition, **are produced prenatally and retained for our entire
>     lifespan**](http://www.pnas.org/content/103/33/12219.full)

---

I want to throw in a philosophical side note and quote computer scientist [Steve Grand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Grand):

> **"*Think of an experience from your childhood. Something you remember
>   clearly, something you can see, feel, maybe even smell, as if you were
>   really there. After all, you really were there at the time, weren’t
>   you? How else would you remember it?***
>
> ***But here is the bombshell: you weren’t there.***
>
> ***Not a single atom that is in your body today was there when that event took place … Matter
>   flows from place to place and momentarily comes together to be you.***
>
> ***Whatever you are, therefore, you are not the stuff of which you are
>   made.***
>
> ***If that doesn’t make the hair stand up on the back of your neck,
>   read it again until it does, because it is important."***
>
> [Richard Dawkins uses this quote in his [TED Talk](http://www.ted.com/talks/richard_dawkins_on_our_queer_universe.html) (around 10:20)]

**More:**

- [Times Higher Education: most cells are younger than the individual](http://www.timeshighereducation.co.uk/story.asp?storyCode=198208&sectioncode=26)
- [ABC Science: Regrowth mystery reborn](http://www.abc.net.au/science/articles/2008/11/18/2422506.htm)

Comment: I'm confused; are you throwing in that quote to show that a quote can sound really profound while being completely false, or are you implying that while some _cells_ are never replaced, every single atom actually is?

Comment: @romkyns - The quote is meant to be __philosophical__ food for thought. Does every atom in our body get replaced at one point? I don't know. But since cells have a "metabolism" there is a constant flux of new molecules (and therefore atoms).

Comment: @romkyns: Why do you think the claim about atoms being replaced is completely false?

Comment: Note that @endolith has now asked this as a separate question: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18427/are-all-the-atoms-in-our-bodies-replaced-on-a-regular-basis

Comment: "Not a single atom that is in your body today was there when that event took place" -- does that follow? Even if every atom has been replaced, won't a few have gone out and come back in again, on the "Caesar's last breath" principle? ;-)

Comment: Honestly, it makes my hair stand up on the back of my neck to consider that my neocortical neurons and parts of my eye *aren't* replenished.

Comment: Came across this looking for some info on this general concept. The link on neocortical neurons is a bit out of date these days - there is the concept of adult neurogenesis which occurs in a restricted set of circumstances, discussed in e.g. a relatively recent review https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1934590918301668 - it is a much less dramatic cell growth than other bodily systems, but it isn't true to say that we never grow new brain cells.

Answer (score 16):

**No, it isn't true that all the cells in our body are replaced every 3/7/10 years.**

Some cells are never replaced.

In this article about the eye:

R.G.A. Faragher,
B. Mulholland, S.J. Tuft,
S. Sandeman, P.T. Khaw, [Brief review on aspects of aging and the eye: Aging and the cornea](http://bjo.bmj.com/content/81/10/814.full#ref-3) Br J Ophthalmol 1997;81:814-817 doi:10.1136/bjo.81.10.814

they explain:

> **Non-dividing cells are those from static cell populations (exemplified by cerebral neurons) which never divide during adult life.**

To support this, they cite an earlier article (which I haven't read):

Leblond CP(1964) Classification of cell populations on the basis of their proliferative behaviour. Natl Cancer Inst Monogr 14:119–149.

Comment: Does it logically follow that non-dividing cells never die or are never replaced? Could they be replaced by stem cells? Just curious.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt they are never replaced. If they die, they're gone. That's why some diseases and injuries (like certain eye problems) can never be healed by regenerating tissue.

Comment: Also true for most neurons

Comment: Rather, for all neurons.

Comment: @Alenanno: [Perhaps not](http://www.nautis.com/2006/10/do-neurons-regenerate/), according to somewhat recent research.

Comment: @Oddthinking Never heard of that... I'll look into it if I have time! Thanks for the link. :)

Comment: @Alenanno: just do a Pubmed search for neurogenesis :) new neurons can definitely be generated even in adults, and not only in response to injury.

Comment: Yeah, you should remove the the reference to neurons, I have also heard that it has been learned that they do in fact reproduce, just not as often as most other cells.

Comment: @Mark Rogers: I wouldn't remove the reference to neurons. Most neurons will last for a lifetime and the physiological function of neuronal reproduction is different from that of, say, skin cells.

Comment: @nico - yes but it kind of confuses the answer since it focuses on a cell type that does in fact reproduce.  Therefore it's a bad example.

Comment: @MarkRogers, my understanding is that only some neurons (i.e. in the Hippocampus) are shown to have this reproductive property.

Comment: @Oddthinking, fair enough.